# How to run a jQuery function after all and any other javascript has run

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, blocking, preloading

I have a photo gallery page hosted on a CMS (Squarespace) which has some of it's own scripts which load the thumbnails asynchronously.

The actual large images however are not preloaded, so I decided to add my own script into the mix to just make the browser load those larger images into the cache in the background, like this:

```
(function($) {
  var cache = [];
  // Arguments are image paths relative to the current page.
  $.preLoadImages = function() {
    var args_len = arguments.length;
    for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
      var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
      cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
      cache.push(cacheImage);
    }
  }
})(jQuery)

$(window).load(function(){
$.preLoadImages(
    "/picture/1.jpg",
    "/picture/2.jpg", //etc.
   );
});
```

I placed my code in a $(window).load() because this is a background script and it's not essential it even runs at all, it's just to improve performance.

However, I think this script is somehow blocking the CMS's own thumbnail preloading script.

Am I right? And most importantly, **is there a way to dictate that my script only run after all other scripts on the page have run?**

cheers

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is always running, the `hover` event for example is firing constantly, `mousemove`, etc...there's no "end" to the script run.

However in your case, this shouldn't block any other preloading...also you can use `document.ready` here, since you don't actually need images loaded before your code executes.

In fact, you're actually slowing down the page by using `window.load` instead...since the preloading starts later, when it could be parallelized with other downloads earlier by the browser.  Instead use `document.ready`, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $.preLoadImages(
    "/picture/1.jpg",
    "/picture/2.jpg", //etc.
   );
});
```

Comment: thanks nick. that makes sense. However, my script is somehow blocking the thumbnail preloading... I don't know how, but the effect is consistent and significant. Could it be something to do with the limits of the browser connections...?

Comment: @andy - It could, if they're on the same domain, the actual HTTP spec says 2 connections per domain at a time, which IE in particular obeys (others allow pipelining easier).  Can give the images a different URL?, for example `http://static.mydomain.com/Images/....`, this would allow *another* 'n' number of connections, because it treats it as another domain from `www.` for example.

Comment: hey Nick, thanks for the extra snippet, I actually tried ready() first, but was getting the block, so then I though window.load() would help, but of course the thumbnails are being loaded async those that wouldn't make a difference... right? maybe I'm completely wrong, I'm assuming it's a block because the thumbnails only load after all my images have loaded in the background

Comment: @nick: ahh... ok, yeah, they are all the same domain... hmmm

Comment: that's why I was wondering if I could somehow only have my loader run in the background after the thumbnail stuff has run. However, I'd like to do that without having to know anything about the other scripts...

Comment: Try `setTimeout(function() { $.preLoadImages("/picture/1.jpg", "/picture/2.jpg", //etc. ); }, 20);`, does it have the effect you want?  Effectively you're just giving a slight buffer for the current thread to execute...of course if you could show their pre-loading code, I could give you a more-sure way to do this :)

Comment: thanks nick. yeah, I've just created a support ticket just to get a direction to their script. I thought about the timeout but it's not as elegant as I'd like..hmm

Comment: @andy - The timeout can even be 0, the goal is to have it start after the current execution thread executes, not that is actually waits an arbitrary amount of time :)

Comment: ahhh... right, I see, yes of course. that's because timeout start a whole different thread, is that why?

Comment: @andy - Good way to think of it...JavScript's actually single-threaded for *most* things...think of it as getting bumped to the end :)

Comment: ahh... genius! thanks man. Well look, I had a quick test and still doesn't seem to be working, so maybe it's their funky script. I'll play around with it a bit more later and report back

Answer (score 2):

Scripts are loaded top down, and body onloads are normally appended to existing onloads - so as long as that $(function().. is at the end of the page, it'll be ran last. (last (as per nick's comment) meaning the initial parse/run of the document)

Comment: This is *kind of* true, in the case of jQuery (usually) most code is attached to a `ready` handler, which is executed later, so while it's evaluated/hooked up in that order, the actual work is done later, when the `ready` event happens.

Comment: thanks dan. So, are you saying I don't need the .ready() or .load()? just call the function at the bottom of the page?

Comment: @andy - For the code you posted, there's no reason to wait for either, if you were doing something that needed DOM elements to be ready, you need `document.ready`, if you're not messing with any, no need.